# System Monitor List Not In Any Order

Tags: unity, 17.04, system

I noticed that my system monitor is out of sorts, that is to say it no longer shows processes in any kind of order. How can I set it to list in alphabetical order again? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the column header! First click with sort ascending, second will be descending and third click will reset.
Have a look at this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv5s0.png). Here I have clicked on `Process Name`.

Comment: Thanks! But it is still out of order. It's listing processes by owner. Is there a way to list them alphabetical?

Comment: Just one small test you can perform:
Start `gnome-system-montor` from the commandline and see if you are getting some gtk errors. If so I suggest you reinstall `gtk` and related packages. (By the way I am assuming you have `gnome` and not `kde`.)

Comment: I'm using Unity 7, but I also have Gnome Shell 3.24 installed. I'm using the Unity DE. I launched it from the commandline, no errors. It's still a mess!

Comment: After trying again to sort the order, I have it set. Thanks for your help!